# How to center 320x480 app in 320x568 window?

Tags: ios, iphone-5

I have a 320x480 app that I want to center for 320x568 screens.  I basically want it to looks like it does by default with the black bars on top and bottom of the screen, but I want to put in my own border.  I thought it would be simple enough to add a second UIWindow at 320x568 to my MainWindow.xib file, add it as a new outlet to my app delegate, and then check in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` if the screen size is 320x568, and set the window to the 320x568 version.  That's causing problems when presenting other view controllers from  my main view controller though.  Any simple way to just center the window on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a container view controller.

If your root view controller is currently `RootViewController`, create `RootViewControllerContainerViewController` (or something more snappy than that), which creates an instance of the old root view controller and adds it to itself with `addSubview:` and `addChildViewController:`. Then position and size the view however you want, adding whatever other views you like around the outside.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to figure out how to do it from the viewcontroller level and create a custom viewcontroller that just handles that one piece of UI. Then you can subclass every other viewcontroller that you want to support that and import it in your project's .pch file so its a fast change.